# How to create Angular 6 component with multiple ng-templates?

Tags: angular, templates, angular2-template, markup

I've been reading a lot regarding Angular's templates but I didn't find anything that would closely resemble what I'm trying to archieve, not to mention that templating in Angular 2+ is confusing as hell which doesn't make the task easier than it should be.

I'd like to know how can I do something like this (or if it's even possible):

```
<my-form>
  <ng-template [for]="title">Users</ng-template>
  <ng-template [for]="content">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="username">
      <input type="text" name="password">
    </form>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template [for]="footer">
    <button (click)="edit()">Edit</button>
    <button (click)="delete()">Delete</button>
  </ng-template>
</my-form>
```

So, the idea would be that my `my-form` component would have stuff like markup, styles, and common stuff that would apply to all these "common forms" I want to create in my application. I've been googling all day without avail, only to find [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/use-ng-template-c72852c37fba) which *kinda* resembles what I'm trying to do, but it's not close and the article is also hard to understand for me.

Note: I don't even know if the `[for]` tag is accurate, this is off the top of my head. Custom tags would work (eg. `<my-form-title></my-form-title>`, `<my-form-content></my-form-content>`, `<my-form-footer></my-form-footer>` and so on).

Can someone here please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Angular structural directive turns the element it's attached to with a ng-template, so you can use custom directives to "mark" children as templates.

First you create a bunch of directives for the customizable parts of your component:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myFormTitle]'
})
export class TitleDirective {}

@Directive({
  selector: '[myFormContent]'
})
export class ContentDirective {}

@Directive({
  selector: '[myFormFooter]'
})
export class FooterDirective {}
```

You use `@ContentChild` to query the component tree to grab the templates created by these directives:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-form',
  templateUrl: './my-form.component.html',
})
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
  @ContentChild(TitleDirective, {read: TemplateRef})
  titleTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ContentChild(ContentDirective, {read: TemplateRef})
  contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  @ContentChild(FooterDirective, {read: TemplateRef})
  footerTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor() { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this)
  }
}
```

And then you render these in your component template as usual:

```
<form>
  <h1>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="titleTemplate"></ng-container>
  </h1>
  <hr/>
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTemplate"></ng-container>
  <hr/>
  <small>
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="footerTemplate"></ng-container>
  </small>
</form>
```

You use this component like this:

```
<my-form>
  <span *myFormTitle>BIG LETTERS</span>
  <div *myFormContent>
    <label>Name: <input name='name'/></label>
  </div>
  <span *myFormFooter>
    yadda blah
  </span>
</my-form>
```

You can also use the directive [microsyntax](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#microsyntax) in the `*myFormTitle` etc. attributes if you're passing a context to the templates; or to access the inherited context. I'm not going to go in depth into that here though since it doesn't really fit your use case.